# how to togglebutton  hold all  button states for all the table rows.in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to handle toogle button on every and each on tableviewcell in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293218/how-to-handle-toogle-button-on-every-and-each-on-tableviewcell-in-iphone)

hi friend i try this code but my tableviewcell is Reusable when i am scroll and  my image which is enabled on click is disappear i am create toggle button for image call on cell

i want show my image on button which is on cell when i scroll cell then my image should stay on that button cell which cell i was clicked

```
-(void)changeMapType:(UIButton*)sender
{
    changeimagetype =!changeimagetype;
   sender.selected = changeimagetype;


    [self.tableView reloadData];

}



 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];



        mimageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        mimageButton.frame=CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 20);
        mimageButton.tag = 1;               
        [mimageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_ON.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [mimageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_OF.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:mimageButton];
        [mimageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeMapType:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [onButtonView release]; 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cells are created and destroyed as they are scrolled on and off screen. Your setting if you set the state of the cell without storing it, you'll lose the state as it goes on and off screen.

You need to store the state of the toggle for that cell and restore it as it appears and disappears.

I have an [short example project](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/585261/CheckedTableView.zip) about maintaining state in table view cells

Answer (score 0):

One way is what Abizer suggested you and the another way is take an Array, Store the selected buttons tag in the array and while displaying the button in the cellForRowAtIndex method. check out whether the buttons tag is in that array or not. If its there then show your selected button image else unselected buttons image.

Answer (score -1):

Remove it

```
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
```

and Write this line

```
     NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d%d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
```

Comment: This will remove the re-usability of the cell.. which don't seem to be good.

Comment: ya, I know it will remove re-usability, but as there are no issue if there are no large amount of cells,

Comment: no matter, iPhone is fast device, it doesn't mean even 200 rows are